# Should I write in my resume, the college degree that I shifted from

Tags: resume

Here is my situation, I am planning to apply to a certain semiconductor company and they are hiring for junior software developers. I took IT-related courses which I recently finished. When I entered college, I first took Electronics Engineering but I shifted to IT. Should I add my unfinished course (which is Electronics Engineering) in my resume, even though I didn't finish it?

I am thinking that since it is a semiconductor company and even though I am applying for software developer, it might be a good thing to show that I had some experience with electronics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I omit a degree and related work experience from my resume if I don't want to work in that area?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18447/can-i-omit-a-degree-and-related-work-experience-from-my-resume-if-i-dont-want-t)

Comment: Did you get a minor in your original major?

Comment: That dupe target is the opposite of this question.

Comment: Take a look at the person specification for the job.  Did the electronics engineering course teach you any of the skills listed in that person specification?  If so, then certainly mention it.

Comment: If you finished and received a grade in the course then it would/should be listed as relevant coursework.  If you dropped the course and did it finish, it’s not really relevant

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, nothing could be **better and more positive**.  Simply keep it BRIEF. You have the dream college resume.

Answer (score 0):

How much coursework did you do in electronics engineering?  Did you get a minor or some other recognition of that coursework?  The situation is very different if you did one or two introductory courses and then changed your major than if you were in the electronics engineering program through the end of your junior year and ended up with a minor.

If you got a minor or some other formal recognition of the coursework, you can certainly list that.  Assuming you didn't end up with some formal recognition of the coursework-- you didn't get a minor or a concentration or a certificate-- you can always list the classes you took as additional coursework.  Something like

```
University of South StackExchangia  2015 - 2019 
Bachelor of Science in IT 
Additional coursework: electronics engineering I, diodes and things III, and googling 101
```

Whether it makes sense to do so will depend on how far you got in the program-- it's obviously much more useful if you're listing upper-level classes rather than introductory classes.  As you get more professional experience, that's also the sort of information that you'd remove relatively quickly from your resume to save space for details of that professional experience.